# How can I get access to orderBy settings in a Eloquent/Builder instance?

Tags: laravel-4

I have a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder instance, something like:

```
$items = \Items::where('type', $type)->orderBy('order', 'asc');
```

After that how can I access the "orderBy" clause by just having $items?

What I want to have at the end is something like:

```
$orderBy = $items->orders;
var_dump($orderBy);
```

> $orderBy = array(2) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(5) "order"
>     [1]=>
>     string(3) "asc"
>   }

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean just "get items" with a specific order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for this question. At first I was like "no way - cant be done".

But I did some exploring in the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder class - and it turns out you can! Is there nothing Taylor hasnt thought of?

```
$orderBy = $items->getQuery()->orders;
var_dump($orderBy);
```

You can actually get the full history of the query - here is a list I found

```
$aggregate = $items->getQuery()->aggregate;
$columns = $items->getQuery()->columns;
$distinct = $items->getQuery()->distinct;
$joins = $items->getQuery()->joins;
$limit = $items->getQuery()->limit;
$unions = $items->getQuery()->unions;
$from = $items->getQuery()->from;
$wheres = $items->getQuery()->wheres;
$groups = $items->getQuery()->groups;
$havings = $items->getQuery()->havings;
$offset = $items->getQuery()->offset;
$lock = $items->getQuery()->lock;
```